# Setting IsEnabled to true or false based on property from View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

Expected Behavior

1. There are ComboBox and DatePicker.
2. On Selection changed of the combo box, depending on the combobox selection the DatePicker should be enabled or disabled.

How I am trying to implement

XAML code for Date Interval and Date Picker

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource viewByInterval}}"
          SelectedValuePath="Value"
          SelectedItem="{Binding IntervalMode,Mode=TwoWay}" />

<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate,Mode=TwoWay}"
            IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EndDateEnabled[0],Mode=TwoWay}">
```

View Model code for changing the EndDateEnabled

```
public bool EndDateEnabled { get; set; }

public DateMode IntervalMode
{
    get
    {
        return _dateModeValue;
    }
    set
    {
        _dateModeValue = value;
        EndDateEnabled =  (value == DateMode.CustomDateRange);                
    }
}
```

I am unable to achieve the functionality.
Please advice.

Comment: Please read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and format your code properly next time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `[0]` part (it's a bool, not a collection), and the binding doesn't need to be `TwoWay`:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EndDateEnabled}"
```

You also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your ViewModel, and raise the `PropertyChanged` event for the `EndDateEnabled` property (and for all properties that your view is bound to):

```
private bool _endDateEnabled;
public bool EndDateEnabled
{
    get { return _endDateEnabled; }
    set
    {
        if (value != _endDateEnabled)
        {
            _endDateEnabled = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("EndDateEnabled");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `EndDateEnabled` can also be a computed property with only a getter:

```
public bool EndDateEnabled
{
    get { return _dateModeValue == DateMode.CustomDateRange; }
}
```

In this case you need to call `OnPropertyChanged("EndDateEnabled")` in the `DateModeValue` setter, so that the binding is refreshed.

Comment: Hax, writing my answer while i improve the question.

Comment: `PropertyChanged` should only be fired if the property *changed*, i.e. `if (field != value)`.

Comment: @H.B., strictly speaking, you're correct, but it doesn't really matter; worst case, the binding is refreshed unnecessarily, but it's usually not a major issue, unless the property is assigned *very* frequently...

Comment: ...or if the refresh causes a huge view hierarchy to be recreated. Well, my opinion is pretty simple anyway: If not necessary, why put code in the answer.

Comment: @H.B., it won't happen, because the target property of the binding is a dependency property, and DPs already check whether the assigned value is the same as the current one

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems that I see. First, your binding to EndDateEnabled should look more like:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Path=EndDateEnabled}"
```

The [0] isn't valid or necessary since the target of the binding is just a plan bool property.
The TwoWay shouldn't apply here, I don't think, but it doesn't hurt to have it.

The backing ViewModel should implement INotifyPropertyChanged in order to notify the UI that the property has changed. The code for the EndDateEnabled property might end up looking something like:

```
private bool endDateEnabled = false;
public bool EndDateEnabled 
{
    get { return endDateEnabled; }
    set 
    {
        if (endDateEnabled != value)
        {
            endDateEnabled = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("EndDateEnabled"));
        }
    }
}
```

I did that from memory so it may not be perfect but it is the general idea.